# Problemas com localização de imagem no Spring Framework

Tags: java, html, imagem, spring, thymeleaf

Estou usando o Spring e Thymeleaf:

Tenho uma imagem no diretório:

> resources/imagem/telescope.png

Quando abro a página posts.html (home),localizada no endereço abaixo, a imagem é exibida.

> http://localhost:8080/BuscaServicos/

Código para chamar a imagem na posts.html (home):

```
<img src="resources/imagem/telescope.png">
```

Porem quando clico em um link da página home para chamar um serviço no HomeController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/categoria/{link}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView postByCategoria(@PathVariable("link") String link, ModelMap model) {

    List<Postagem> postagems = postagemService.findByCategoria(link);
    model.addAttribute("postagens", postagems);
    return new ModelAndView("posts.html", model);
}
```

O método acima devolve uma view para a pagina posts.html novamente ,não consigo mais carregar a imagem o que esta acontecendo?

No inspecionar ele diz que não pode carreagar o src da imagem que esta montado assim pelo Spring:

> http://localhost:8080/BuscaServicos/categoria/resources/imagem/telescope.png

Realmente a imagem não esta nesse endereço!
Ela ainda continua aqui:

> resources/imagem/telescope.png

Não entendo porque ele criou essa concatenação para o src da imagem!

Nas classe de configuração eu habilitei tudo que estiver na pagina resources 
para ser carregado:

```
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
...
...
```

Comment: Você passou um endereço relativo, por isso ele "concatenou", se colocar uma `/` no endereço da imagem, o comportamento não vai ser esse

Comment: O que você usa na View? Somente html?

Comment: Se utitilizar thymeleaf pode fazer assim: `<img th:src="@{/resources/imagem/telescope.png}">`

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza Obrigado! Era isso , mesmo, esqueci de mencionar que eu estva usando thymeleaf!!! Já fazia um tempo que não trabalhava com o Thymeleaf!! Foi tiro e queda!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse problema ocorre por que está informando o caminho relativo da imagem, dessa forma o sistema vai utilizar como base a url atual e adicionar a que você informou.

Para poder utilizar o caminho absoluto, deve utilizar a url com uma barra no início.

Utilizar o caminho absoluto pode lhe trazer problemas futuros, por exemplo: se o contexto da aplicação mudar, o endereço absoluto não será mais válido, por isso o thymeleaf tem uma sintaxe especial para poder informar endereços, no seu caso ficaria assim:

```
 <img th:src="@{/resources/imagem/telescope.png}">
```

Note a barra no começo da url indicando que o caminho é absoluto, note também que eu utilizei `@{endereço}` junto de `th:src`, o `@{}` vai pegar o contexto `(BuscaServicos)` e adicionar antes da url